# Minimum of quadratic interpolation polynomial - proof

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

Given function $f$ with $a < c < b$, $f(a) > f(c) < f(b)$ the interpolating polynomial is defined as $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ where
$$
a = \frac{(b-c)f(a)+(c-a)f(b)+(a-b)f(c)}{(b-c)(a-c)(a-b)} \\
b = -\frac{(b^2-c^2)f(a)+(c^2-a^2)f(b)+(a^2-b^2)f(c)}{(b-c)(a-c)(a-b)}
$$
I need to prove that
$$
x_{min} = \frac{(b^2-c^2)f(a)+(c^2-a^2)f(b)+(a^2-b^2)f(c)}{2\left((b-c)f(a)+(c-a)f(b)+(a-b)f(c)\right)} 
$$

Now, calculating the first derivative $p'(x) = 2ax + b$ and setting it to $0$ results in $x = \frac{-b}{2a} = \frac{(b^2-c^2)f(a)+(c^2-a^2)f(b)+(a^2-b^2)f(c)}{2\left((b-c)f(a)+(c-a)f(b)+(a-b)f(c)\right)} $

However, this is just a stationary point. I'd like to prove that this is a minimum.

The second derivative is $p''(x) = 2a = \frac{(b-c)f(a)+(c-a)f(b)+(a-b)f(c)}{(b-c)(a-c)(a-b)}$. I'd like to show $2a > 0$, as that would make the $x_{min}$ actual minimum. Denominator $(b-c)(a-c)(a-b)$ is always positive since $(a-c) < 0, (a-b) < 0 \implies (a-b)(a-c) > 0$ and $(b-c) > 0$. However, I don't see why the nominator is positive as well.

Am I missing something fundamental? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since $a$ is an arbitrary constant, you cannot force $2a > 0$. E.g. we could have chosen $a = -1, b = 0, c = 1$ and the question is still valid. Check the setup to see if the condition is $ 0 < a < b < c$.  Note that equations that you gave are identities (the algebra cancels out), as opposed to formulas.

Comment: Maybe your last line holds a clue. Saying that "We also pick $a,b,c$ such that $f(a) > f(c) < f(b)$ does necessitate $ a > 0$. So,  you might need to provide more context.

Comment: @CalvinLin we know $f$ is unimodal and $f(a) > f(c) < f(b)$.

Comment: How do we know that $f(a) > f(c) < f(b)$? Is that an assumption you're working with? If yes, then that implies $  0 < a $.

Comment: This is an assumption which I missed when I wrote the question. Could you show me, why is $0 < a$?

Comment: If the quadratic satisfies $ f(a) > f(c) < f(b) $ for $ a < c < b$, is it upward facing or downward facing? Hence, is the leading coefficient positive or negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a quadratic satisfies $ f(a) > f(c) < f(b) $ for values $ a < c < b$, is it upward facing or downward facing?

Hence, is the leading coefficient positive or negative?

Hence, conclude that $ a > 0$, so the extrema is a minimum.

Comment: Of course the leading coefficient must be positive. Obvious now, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g$ be a polynomial function of degree 2 whose graph is a concave parabola (which does not satisfy the condition $g(a),g(b)>g(c)$). Then if we interpolate $g$ in $a,b,c$ then the interpolating polynomial of $g$ coincides with $g$ and does not have a minimum. This suggest that some additional condition is needed to prove the interpolating polynomial $f$ has a minimum.
You have already prove the denominator of the fraction defining $a$ is positive. As far as the nominator is concern:
$$(b-c)f(a)+(c-a)f(b)+(a-b)f(c)= (b-c)f(a)+(c-a)f(b)+(a-c+c-b)f(c) = (b-c)(f(a)-f(c))+(c-a)(f(b)-f(c))>0$$
provided $f(a),f(b)>f(c)$. This shows this additional condition is sufficient to get an interpolating polynomial with a minimum. Notice that $a<c<b$ and $f(a),f(b)>f(c)$ is a convexity condition, since this condition entails that $(c,f(c))$ lies below the line passing through $(a,f(a)), (b,f(b))$.